# JavaScript framework with rich ajax requests and middle level ui

Tags: ajax, javascript-framework

I have to choose right js framework for web project. The structure of project consist from two separate modules:
1) Backend which sends data in xml/Json formats
2) html5 + JavaScript which receives data from backend and display it in browser.
Our team would be responsible for UI and JavaScript. I need to choose javascript framework.. (jQuery, ExtJs, Mootools, Prototype, DoJo, YUI, etc)
The ui is not complex but it contains small photo gallery, paging, popups, a lot of ajax, cross browsing..

Answer (score 0):

How good is your team with CSS and Browser Compatibility?

If the answer is "not very" then I would suggest a rich framework such as ExtJs or DoJo that produces the html/css content for you.

If you are reasonably competent, then a behaviour only framework such as jQuery would give you more flexibility. There is of course also jQuery-UI which builds on jQuery base but falls into the first category.

Also be mindful of the future usefulnes of the skillsets required - good HTML/CSS/jQuery skills are widely used. By comparison few projects will use extJS. You may have a difficult job providing this as a rationale to management, but hopefully you get my point.

Perhaps the following reference may also help you decide?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks